# Why this plugin doesn't work with media upload page?

Tags: ajax, attachments, post-status

I found this plugin very useful [ajaxed-status](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33442/custom-column-for-changing-post-status-via-ajax)
It was created for post and page, and I want to apply it on media library. so I commented out the line `if (is_admin()  /*&& ($pagenow=='edit.php' )*/)` and added this:

```
add_filter ( "manage_upload_columns", array ($this, 'add_new_columns' ) );
add_action ( "manage_media_custom_column", array ($this, 'manage_columns' ), 0, 2 );
```

Then, I got the status column on Media Library list page, and I can click the status to make it change to new status. But, the change can't be saved. From Firebug, I can see the ajax response is correct. I hope the original author, @Bainternet , or other people, may  help figure this out.

---

**update**

I tried update_post_meta to save the $status as meta. It works. Just can't save it as post_status by wp_update_post.

Comment: I'll take alook as soon as i get home

Comment: I guess it has to do with the fact that attachments are set post_status inherited.

Comment: I guess the same. Maybe wp_update_post updates attachments differently. Anything might be bad if I update status in post table directly?

Comment: @Bainternet , I changed the scripts that created the toggle links,  I use $status as an argument of the function and added "inherit" as one of the switch cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I find the answer-- wp-include/post.php:

```
if ( ! in_array( $post_status, array( 'inherit', 'private' ) ) )
    $post_status = 'inherit';
```

So, whatever status will be saved as "inherit".