# update custom taxonomy with Ajax in edit.php file

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, ajax

I created Custom Psot Type and Custom Taxonomy.
I recover, for each CPT element its custom taxonomy.
here is a screenshot:

[image]

now , i want update the coustom taxonomy for the CPT element with ajax without opening the post.php .
is there a solution? help please

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found a solution similar to mine [Custom column for changing post status via ajax](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33442/custom-column-for-changing-post-status-via-ajax)